# How do I switch from a recommended release to a development snapshot?

Tags: 9, updating

Is there a non-Drush, Ludwig way to switch from the recommended release of a module to a development snapshot in Drupal 9, for example copying the development snapshot files and run update.php?

The Drush answer for Drupal 7 given in [How can I update from the recommended release of a module to it development snapshot?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19912/how-to-switch-from-recommended-release-of-module-to-dev-release) suggests to do that.
In my case, I want to switch to the development snapshot of the Address module to resolve the *doctrine/collections missing when using Ludwig on Drupal 9* issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can install the dev version of Drupal modules by setting the version constraint as `1.x-dev`. For example: `composer require drupal/token:1.x-dev`.

Read more: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies#specify-version

Comment: I'm using Ludwig insted of composer. Is there a non-composer way for setting the version constraint? Thx!

Comment: No clue. Ludwig is a non-standard method of managing Drupal code, so you'll find that there won't be much support for Ludwig issues - you'll likely need to work through them yourself for the most part.

Comment: Composer is the standard.

Comment: You may want to lock it to a specific commit when using a branch by appending #COMMIT-HASH to the version. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies#s-requiring-a-specific-commit-of-a-module

Comment: Composer is the standard/the best way to go, but there certainly  is  a reason/demand for what Ludwig offert since there is more than 10k sites that use it.

Comment: It's simply not worth using it because you won't find universal support like you will for Composer in the PHP ecosystem.

Comment: How many of those 10k are Drupal 8+ though? Vanishingly few I would imagine. Ludwig isn’t relevant for Drupal 8+, it really would be a good idea to move your site to the supported package workflow

Comment: Composer can be daunting if you've never worked with the command line, but it's actually not so hard to learn, and once you do, you'll never go back. It can be frustrating when Composer reports a conflict, but Composer support in Drupal is extensive, and there are Composer support communities as well. And fixing a conflict reported by Composer is better than having an unrealized conflict causing bugs in a non-Composer system. Here's a series I wrote on Composer for Drupal users that may help: https://www.morpht.com/blog/drupal-and-composer-part-1-understanding-composer